# mongodb data retrieval from nested fields using flask pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm passing id and customer id fields as parameters to get the document. With my below code I'm only able to fetch only those fields of a document. How do I get entire document with multiple fields as parameter?

Code:

```
@reviews.route('/<inp_id>/<cat_id>', methods=['GET'])
def index(inp_id, cat_id):
    my_coln = mongo_connection.db.db_name
    document = collection.find_one({'id': inp_id}, {'category.id': cat_id})
```

Result:

```
{
  "category": {
    "id": "13"
  }, 
  "_id": "5cdd36cd8a348e81d8995d3b"
}
```

I want:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "id": "1", 
    "name": "Kit Data"
  }, 
  "category": {
    "id": "13", 
    "name": "TrainKit"
  }, 
  "review_date": "2019-05-06", 
  "phrases": null, 
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all your filters in the first dict, the second one is for projection.

```
document = collection.find_one({'id': inp_id, 'category.id': cat_id})
```

Your original query, `collection.find_one({'id': inp_id}, {'category.id': cat_id})` means give me only `category.id` (and nothing else (well, apart from `_id` which is returned by default)) of a document in which the value of `id` equals `inp_id`.

Comment: getting result only for the first document. I'm getting null for other combination of id's even though record is present.

Comment: because of mixed data types for the same field I was getting null. It works now